# Powershell convert sddl output within a for-each loop

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am writing a script that will grab the audit settings of all GPOs in my Active Directory forest. I get most of what I need with this:

```
Get-Gpo -All |
    ForEach-Object {$GPO = $_.DisplayName; Get-Acl -Path ("AD:\" + $_.Path) -Audit |
        Select-Object @{n="GPO";e={$GPO}},PSChildName,AuditToString,Audit,AccessToString,sddl} | 
            select GPO,AuditToString,AccessToString,sddl | 
                Format-list |
                    out-file C:\Users\scott\Desktop\gpo_acl.txt
```

The output from this looks like this:

```
GPO           : Server 2019
AuditToString : Everyone Success  
                Everyone Failure  
                Everyone Success  
                Everyone Success  
Sddl          : PAI(A;CIIO;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;CO)(A;CI;LCRPLORC;;;ED)

GPO           : Computer Quarantine
AuditToString : Everyone Success  
                Everyone Failure  
                Everyone Success  
                Everyone Success  
Sddl          : PAI(A;CIIO;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;CO)(A;CI;LCRPLORC;;;ED)
```

(I truncated the Sddl output because it would make information public that I didn't want public.)
What I'm now trying to accomplish is to make that Sddl output more human readable. I can manually copy the Sddl output into a command like this:

```
ConvertFrom-SddlString -sddl "PAI(A;CIIO;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;CO)(A;CI;LCRPLORC;;;ED)" -type ActiveDirectoryRights |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty DiscretionaryAcl
```

And it gives me output that looks nicer, like this:

```
NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: AccessAllowed (CreateChild, Delete, DeleteChild, DeleteTree, ExecuteKey, FullControl, GenericExecute, GenericRead, GenericWrite, ListChildren, ListObject, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadControl, ReadProperty, Self, WriteDacl, WriteKey, WriteOwner, WriteProperty)
```

I'm trying to get that nicer output within the for-each loop I posted in the beginning. A colleague suggested adding this hashtable at the end of the select-object:

```
Get-Gpo -All |
    ForEach-Object {$GPO = $_.DisplayName; Get-Acl -Path ("AD:\" + $_.Path) -Audit |
        Select-Object @{n="GPO";e={$GPO}},PSChildName,AuditToString,Audit,AccessToString,sddl @{n="SDDLString";e={ConvertFrom-SddlString($_.sddl)}}} | 
            select GPO,AuditToString,AccessToString,sddl | 
                Format-list |
                    out-file C:\Users\scott\Desktop\gpo_acl.txt
```

but it prints the name of the object instead of the content. Ideally, I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
GPO           : Server 2019
AuditToString : Everyone Success  
                Everyone Failure  
                Everyone Success  
                Everyone Success  
Sddl          : NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: AccessAllowed (CreateChild, Delete, DeleteChild, DeleteTree, ExecuteKey, FullControl, GenericExecute, GenericRead, GenericWrite, ListChildren, ListObject, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadControl, ReadProperty, Self, WriteDacl, WriteKey, WriteOwner, WriteProperty)

GPO           : Computer Quarantine
AuditToString : Everyone Success  
                Everyone Failure  
                Everyone Success  
                Everyone Success  
Sddl          : NT AUTHORITY\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users: AccessAllowed (GenericExecute, GenericRead, ListChildren, ListObject, ReadControl, ReadProperty)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: AccessAllowed (CreateChild, Delete, DeleteChild, DeleteTree, ExecuteKey, FullControl, GenericExecute, GenericRead, GenericWrite, ListChildren, ListObject, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadControl, ReadProperty, Self, WriteDacl, WriteKey, WriteOwner, WriteProperty)
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: You would be best servied by including a specimen of your desired output.

Comment: Also, can you double-check the code you posted?
I would expect this whole line to throw an error "Select-Object @{n="GPO";e={$GPO}},PSChildName,AuditToString,Audit,AccessToString,sddl} @{n="SDDLString";e=(ConvertFrom-SddlString($_.sddl)}"

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my syntax error. Fixed now.

My desired output would be the output I currently get, but with the sddl line in human readable form. Something like this:

Comment: Go back and edit your post

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post to add my vision at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might get you something closer to what you were expecting; I'm sure you can pop back in the Out-File yourself:

```
Get-Gpo -All |
    ForEach-Object {$GPO = $_.DisplayName; Get-Acl -Path ("AD:\" + $_.Path) -Audit |
        Select-Object -Property `
           @{n="GPO";e={$GPO}}, `
           AuditToString, `
           @{n="SDDLString";e={(ConvertFrom-SddlString -Sddl $_.Sddl).SystemAcl}}
    } | Format-List
```

Mind the line breaks; they're just here so you don't have to side scroll

Comment: When I run that, it prompts me to supply a value for the SDDL parameter. Hitting enter gives me an error. The output still goes to the outfile and the SDDLString is populated with only information for the Everyone group.